# How do I remove users from a shared Google Cloud Print printer?

Tags: google-cloud-print

Once I've added users to a shared printer, I can't figure out how to remove them.  Clicking "share" from the owner's account gives me a menu that's *almost* what I want, but there are no drop-downs by the user roles.  In similar G Suite dialogues, there'd be a drop-down for each user.

[image: Google CLoud Print "Share" dialog]

I hope I'm not going to have to re-create this printer every time I want to remove people.  Is it possible to remove users without doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be an x at the right of each persons email after the "Can Print". Use the grey scroll bar shown in your picture above "invite people" to move right most as it is likely off your current screen view.

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe it. Thanks.